# Connecting Lambda with resources within a VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-redshift, amazon-vpc

A Redshift cluster is within a VPC that has no direct exposure to internet, but can be reached with ssh tunneling.

I have a lambda function that needs to connect both to internet and this Redshift cluster.

What would be the more natural way to do it?

Should I try to ssh tunneling Redshift public IP from my lambda? How would I achieve this?

Should I put my lambda in another 'internet open' VPC and allow VPC peering? Would this mean security issues?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What are you planning to use as a Lambda function trigger?

Comment: It's called within a Step Functions state machine.

Comment: What is your VPC, does it have NAT gateway, private subnets?

Comment: It has no NAT Gateways, has public and also private subnets.

Comment: I'm thinking it just might be as simple as creating a new public subnet and associeate it with the Lambda function. Then should have access to private subnets and also to internet through the gateway. Sorry if it is obvious.

Comment: @Aleix Unfortunately, simply placing a Lambda function in a public subnet does _not_ provide it with access to the Internet.

Comment: @John Rotenstein My mistake.. I meant associate the subnet with the Redshift cluster. It finally worked. Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically have two choices:

- Put the Lambda function in the same VPC as the Amazon Redshift cluster, *or*
- Put the Lambda function *outside* the VPC

If the Lambda function is **in the same VPC so that it can communicate with the Redshift cluster**, and it also requires Internet access, then the configuration would be:

- Attach the Lambda function to private subnet(s)
- Create a **NAT Gateway** or a **NAT Instance** in a public subnet and update
- Update the Route Table of the private subnet(s) to send Internet-bound traffic to the NAT Gateway/NAT Instance

If the Lambda function is *outside* the VPC, it would need some means of accessing the Redshift cluster. This would be rather messy and would probably be bad for security (eg exposing a port to the Internet). I advise against it.

There is a third method that I would not normally suggest, but *might* be suitable for you. It involves:

- Associating the Lambda function with a public subnet
- Attaching an Elastic IP address to the Elastic Network Internet (ENI) that is created by the Lambda function

When a Lambda function attaches to a subnet, it creates an ENI. This is the connection between the Lambda function and the VPC. (Actually, it's a connection between the *containers* that run the Lambda function, and the VPC.)

I noticed that I can attach an Elastic IP address to the ENI and this grants Internet access to the Lambda function. However, **ENIs might be created/destroyed by the Lambda service**, so this wouldn't necessarily keep working. That is, the ENI might not persist, so the Elastic IP address might not always be attached. Therefore, I advise to use this method with caution.

The "correct" method is to use a NAT Gateway or NAT Instance.